# Joint Displays don't work

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have just bought a new monitor LG-27UL550 and I want to use it alongside my old monitor (LG-24UD58). They work well in `Mirror` mode. But it doesn't work standalone or in `Join Displays` mode, i.e. the screen is blank. Can anyone please suggest how can I help it?

I have tried restarting and plugging the HDMI cable in when the PC was off as well as when the PC was on. I have also tried different configurations of HDMI ports just in case. I am also sure that I connect both HDMI cables to my NVidia graphic card, not to the default one.

I have Ubuntu `20.04.6`, NVidia GeForce GTX 1070 with `535.86.05` driver. I am sure that this is the latest version of the available driver.

Here is my output of `xrandr` command for `Mirror` mode:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4384 x 2466, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 4384x2466+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  59.94    50.00    30.00*   29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    23.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
HDMI-1 connected primary 4384x2466+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     30.00*+  29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    29.97    60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Here is the error from `journalctl -xe | grep -i display` when I try `Join Displays`:

```
Sep 08 20:00:17 eugene gnome-shell[7077]: meta_display_get_monitor_in_fullscreen: assertion 'monitor >= 0 && monitor < n_logical_monitors' failed
```

Perhaps I need to increase the `n_logical_monitors` parameter but I don't know how to do it and I'm not sure whether it's safe to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was solved by changing HDMI cable to a more powerful one. Maybe someone would find this ever useful.